# postgres grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am having a db names products where i wanted to select the price of each product based on the id, but the price that i stored in the table is from different sources. So i want one latest price from each of the source.
My table looks like this

```
id | name | source | updated_at | price 
1  | ace  | vanil  | ...        | 100
2  | vax  | vanil  | ...        | 101
3  | tax  | sunyil | ...        | 200
1  | ace  | sunyil | latest     | 99.5
2  | vax  | sunyil | latest     | 100.5
3  | tax  | vanil  | latest     | 199.5
3  | tax  | vanil  | ...        | 220
3  | tax  | vanil  | ...        | 211
3  | tax  | vanil  | ...        | 205
3  | tax  | sunyil | ...        | 211
3  | tax  | vanil  | ...        | 220
3  | tax  | sunyil |latest_time | 220
1  | ace  | sunyil | ...        | 101
```

i want the output to be like this when my where condition is for id=3

```
id | name | source | updated_at | price
 3 | tax  | vanil  | latest time| 199.5
 3 | tax  | sunyil | latest time| 220
```

i tried running the

```
select * from products WHERE id= '3' ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

but this one brings only one row irrespective of the source

could any one help me out with this. I am extremely new to postgres and sql queries. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, source) *
FROM products
WHERE id = 3
ORDER BY id, source, updated_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to do. If you would like to sum the price for the product with id 3 not having the text "..." in the column "updated_at", you can do this query:

```
SELECT id, name, source, updated_at, SUM(price) FROM products 
WHERE id = 3 and updated_at != '...'
GROUP BY id, name, source, updated_at ORDER BY updated_at;
```

See this example and try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=789f860b8c05585cf5fe7981dbfa8f4e)
Modify the query to your desires if necessary.

Comment: I dont want to add the price. 
I want to get one latest row from each source. 
Each source will have many rows for the same id, in which i only need the latest one from each source

Comment: Then you can do SELECT id, name, source, p.updated_at, price FROM products p
JOIN (SELECT MAX(updated_at) updated_at FROM products GROUP BY source) maxp 
ON p.updated_at = maxp.updated_at
WHERE id = 3 ORDER BY source;